# decodeURIComponent not decoding a string from a data attribute

Tags: javascript

I've got a strange issue with decoding an escaped javascript string.

Here is the test code, getting the escaped string from the data attribute doesn't work it just gets printed out raw. The second example works fine.

```
var emailText = $('#emaildata').data('email-text');
var unescapedEmailText = decodeURIComponent(emailText);
alert(unescapedEmailText);

var emailText2 = "Blah blah edit blah foo\x27\x0a\x0a\x0a\x27\x27\x27";
var unescapedEmailText2 = decodeURIComponent(emailText2);
alert(unescapedEmailText2);
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the broken functionality. http://jsfiddle.net/wnegH/2/

I'm sure i'm doing something daft, but what I can't fathom out...

Comment: The decodeURIComponent is a red herring, the data you are passing in is different: http://jsfiddle.net/wnegH/4/

Comment: Are you sure the  $('#emaildata').data('email-text') was encoded before trying to decode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you put inside the `data-email-text` attribute is not a javascript string. So using `\x27` inside it, simply means the `\x27` string as-is and not the corresponding ASCII character.

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wnegH/3/) of how you could achieve the desired effect:

```
<div id="emaildata" data-email-text="Blah%20blah%20edit%20blah%20foo'%0A%0A%0A'''"></div>
```

and then:

```
var emailText = $('#emaildata').data('email-text');
var unescapedEmailText = decodeURIComponent(emailText);
alert(unescapedEmailText);
```

Obviously the string I have used in the `data-email-text` attribute was obtained by invoking the `encodeURIComponent` function on the target string.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript escape sequences (such as `\x27`) have no special meaning in HTML. You need to use [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3) or real characters instead.